# Почему запятая в индексации устарела в C++20?

Tags: c++, операторы, language-lawyer, дизайн-языка, c++20

Почему в C++20 использование оператора `,` в операторе индексации массива `[]` стало устаревшим?

Например, следующий use-case теперь [выдаёт предупреждение](https://godbolt.org/z/Yj55Ge):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int a[42 + 1];

void logging(std::size_t index) {
    std::cout << "[Array access: " << index << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    std::size_t index = 42;
    std::cout << a[logging(index), index] << '\n';
}
```

> warning: top-level comma expression in array subscript is deprecated
> [-Wcomma-subscript]

Comment: Скорее всего, потому что это не имеет особого смысла, и, скорее всего, свидетельствует об ошибке. Если же Вам действительно нужно использовать там запятую, то Вы можете заключить выражение в скобки, тогда компилятор перестанет ругаться (такой случай не является `deprecated`): `a[(logging(index), index)] `

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1161r3.html

Comment: @Croessmah а в других местах почему не сделали тогда?

Comment: @AndreySv приведите мотивацию оттуда в качестве ответа

Comment: Здесь видимо готовят почву для перегрузки `[]` с несколькими параметрами. А в каких еще местах депрекейтить?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat во всех остальных, где можно обойтись без него. Можно было бы  сделать его со значением соединения элементов в `std::tuple`, чтобы поддерживать синтаксис `auto[x,y] = 1, 2;` вместо написания `std::make_tuple`, `std::make_pair` и прочего

Comment: Тут можно только гадать. Мне специальный синтаксис для `tuple` не особо нравится, потому что намертво прибивает часть стандартной библиотеки к языку.

Comment: @dIm0n, тут вообще разный контекст. Как связаны массивы и структурные привязки? И зачем вообще в индексе использовать запятую? Это немного странного выглядит, и скорее вводит в заблужение читающего. Плюс ко всему, не забывайте, что это синтаксический сахар от `*(array + index)`. А теперь подставьте на место `index` содержимое `operator[]` для `a[logging(index), index]` =) Вот почему без скобок это как бы и не должно было работать (об этом, видимо, позаботились разработчики стандарта/компилятора).

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον вы про `auto[x,y] = 1, 2;`? Это не массив, а structured binding. Подобный синтаксис используется в питоне `x, y = 1, 2` и для меня выглядит читаемо. "и не должно было работать" - но работало до с++20 (в с++20 тоже работает, но с предупреждением)

Comment: @dIm0n, и я про то же, структурные привязки, а в примере вопроса массив.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думаю что не было проблем и не путали с [`tuple`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/).

Как указал @andrey-sv [тут](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1161r3.html) там косвенно говорится об этом.

**UPD**

Дополню свободным частичным переводом статьи.

[P1161R3 Deprecate uses of the comma operator in subscripting expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1161r3.html)

> Abstract
>
> We propose to deprecate the use of the comma operator in
> subscripting expressions as they are not very useful, confusing and
> limit futures evolutions of the standard.

Аннотация.

Мы предлагаем отказаться от использования оператора запятой в индексных выражениях, поскольку они не очень полезны, сбивают с толку и ограничивают развитие стандарта будущего.

```
Текуший 
array[x]     // Ok
array[(x,y)] // Ok, если y это index/key
array[x,y]   // Ok, если y это index/key

Предлагаемый
array[x]      // Ok
array[(x,y)]  // Ok, если y это index/key
array[x,y]    // Устаревший, если y это index/key
```

> Currently, a comma can appear in subscript expressions such that `auto z = foo[x, y]` calls the comma operator with `y` as the argument.
> While this is currently unambiguous, it is confusing when encountered
> and error-prone when used.

> The authors think this syntax would be more useful and suited to index
> multidimensional classes such as `mdspan`.

В данный момент запятая в индексных выражениях таких как `auto z = foo[x, y]`, вызывающая оператор запятая с `y` в качестве аргумента. Хотя это в настоящее время выглядит однозначно, это сбивает с толку и приводит к ошибкам при использовании.

Авторы считают, что этот синтаксис будет более полезным и подходит для индексации многомерных классов таких как `mdspan`.

```
mdspan<int, array_property::dimension<2, 3, 5>> foo(/*...*/);
int value = foo[1, 2, 3];
```

> In contexts where comma is given a special meaning, [ Example: in
> lists of arguments to functions ([expr.call]) and lists of
> initializers ([dcl.init]) — end example ] the comma operator as
> described in this subclause can appear only in parentheses.

В тех случаях, когда запятая несёт особый смысл, [Пример: в списках аргументов функций ([expr.call]) и списках инициализаторов ([dcl.init]) - конец примера] оператор запятая, как описано в этом подпункте, может появляются только в скобках.

Comment: А как это связано с `tuple`?

Comment: В ногу со временем. Вот это как связано.

Comment: Не понял. Вы к тому, что в каких-то других языках tuple создаются квадратными скобками?

Comment: Нет круглыми, только вот смысл в корне меняется в зависимости от скобок. Во избежание ошибок лучше вовсе не записывать в квадратных вот в чем мода